# Module '"ng-particles"' has no exported member 'Container'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation, particles.js

I would like to use ng-particles in my angular project, I have installed it using npm i ng-particles and I've added 
*app.ts*

```
import { Container, Main } from 'ng-particles';
export class AppComponent{

  id = "tsparticles";

  /* Starting from 1.19.0 you can use a remote url (AJAX request) to a JSON with the configuration */
  particlesUrl = "http://foo.bar/particles.json";

  /* or the classic JavaScript object */
  particlesOptions = {
    background: {
      color: {
        value: "#0d47a1"
      }
    },
    fpsLimit: 60,
    interactivity: {
      detectsOn: "canvas",
      events: {
        onClick: {
          enable: true,
          mode: "push"
        },
        onHover: {
          enable: true,
          mode: "repulse"
        },
        resize: true
      },
      modes: {
        bubble: {
          distance: 400,
          duration: 2,
          opacity: 0.8,
          size: 40
        },
        push: {
          quantity: 4
        },
        repulse: {
          distance: 200,
          duration: 0.4
        }
      }
    },
    particles: {
      color: {
        value: "#ffffff"
      },
      links: {
        color: "#ffffff",
        distance: 150,
        enable: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        width: 1
      },
      collisions: {
        enable: true
      },
      move: {
        direction: "none",
        enable: true,
        outMode: "bounce",
        random: false,
        speed: 6,
        straight: false
      },
      number: {
        density: {
          enable: true,
          value_area: 800
        },
        value: 80
      },
      opacity: {
        value: 0.5
      },
      shape: {
        type: "circle"
      },
      size: {
        random: true,
        value: 5
      }
    },
    detectRetina: true
  };

  particlesLoaded(container: Container): void {
    console.log(container);
  }

  particlesInit(main: Main): void {
    console.log(main);

    // Starting from 1.19.0 you can add custom presets or shape here, using the current tsParticles instance (main)
  }
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import {NgParticlesModule} from "ng-particles";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        /* AppComponent */
    ],
    imports: [
        /* other imports */ NgParticlesModule /* NgParticlesModule is required*/
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [
        /* AppComponent */
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

*app.html*

```
<ng-particles [id]="id" [options]="particlesOptions" (particlesLoaded)="particlesLoaded($event)" (particlesInit)="particlesInit($event)"></ng-particles>
```

*package.json*

```
"ng-particles": "^2.2.2",
```

and I've followed the steps from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-particles

But I'm getting bunch of errors which I'm not aware of while running
[image]

[image]

Am I missing something?

Please find versions
[image]

Comment: Which Angular and TypeScript versions are you using?

Comment: Hi @Caelan, I have added in my post , Could you please check it?

Comment: Thank you, the issue is with TypeScript 3.7 that not supports `import type`, I’ll release an update for this very soon. Sorry I didn’t tested with that version

Comment: Thank you for the update, If I downgrade the typescript version to 3.6.0, will that support?

Comment: Yes, It will support starting `3.4`. Actually the support below `3.8` is not guaranteed

Comment: I've upgraded the typescript version to 4.2.3 but still getting 4 errors like this `import type import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';` and `{ Container, Main } from 'tsparticles';` so it means `4.2.3` also not supporting `import type`, Could you please tell me which particular **typescript version** I can use that will **support import type**

Comment: I've tried with couple of versions and couldn't find the suitable one, If you suggest the version that support `import type`, It will be so useful

Comment: The `import type` was released in `3.8` and still works. Did you installed the peer dependency `tsparticles`?

Comment: I&#39;m using angular 11 and I got mine to work. I did not import container or main in my component.ts file though. The only issue I was facing was, I needed to install tsparticles after ng-particles

Answer (score 0):

This may Differ Based on everyone projects, but for me just having `ng-particles` in my package.json would not install `tsparticles` (it's peer dependency that has the `Container` type).

Manually installing `tsparticles` (`npm i tsparticles --save`) had solved the issue for me.

Versions:

```
    "tsparticles": "1.36.0",
     "ng-particles": "2.19.0",
     ---- Other Dependencies for reference ---
      "typescript": "4.1.5",
      "@angular/*": "11.2.3",
     (Node: "14.18.0", NPM: 6.14.13)
```